# config.json and using values in app.module.ts providers

Tags: json, angular, nswag, angular-injector

Currently, we are building our angular (v15) application once for each environment we deploy to, since we are using the environment.ts files to handle variable transforms.

I would like to get us to a flow more similar to our backend, AspNetcore, with it's appsettings.json transformations.

Now reading from a JSON file and swapping the tokens is easy enough, but I am struggling with how we can use the values from the JSON file during application start, particularly when defining our NSWAG API Url tokens.

For example:
`{ provide: AUTH_API_BASE_URL, useValue: environment.auth_api_url },`

From the reading and research I've done, the code should look something like this:

```
export function initApp(http: HttpClient) {
  return () => {
    return http.get('assets/config/configuration.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log('Response 1 - ', resp);
      });
  };
}
```

```
    providers: [
      {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: initApp,
        multi: true,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      { provide: AUTH_API_BASE_URL, useValue: <needs to change> },
```

Now, the logging in the above example works and contains everything I would want.  I have tried creating a variable, and a static variable to hold the data, I have also tried using classes declared as dependencies in both providers to try and shuffle the data long so I could use in when declaring the `AUTH_API_BASE_URL` provider.  Every time it comes out as undefined.

I'm not sure if it's a timing issue, I've tried setting the `AUTH_API_BASE_URL` to useFactory with a timeout before getting the value, still no luck.

Is there a way to force it to wait for the `APP_INITIALIZER` to completely finish before moving onto the next one?

Is there a way to set these providers outside of initial app startup?  The following wasn't changing anything for me:

```
Injector.create({providers: [{provide: AUTH_API_BASE_URL, useValue: settings.apiUrls.base_auth_api_url}]});
```

Is there a working way of passing these data between this initial providers? Outside of setting these Base API URLs, what I have now should work for the rest of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can just straight import JSON files with a few tweaks to your tsconfig.

TSConfig - add to "compilerOptions:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

Changed provider setup like so:

```
 { provide: API_BASE_URL, useFactory: (settings: AppSettings) => settings.settings.apiUrls.base_api_url, deps: [AppSettings]},
```

Service wrapper around JSON file looks like:

```
import appSetting from '../assets/config/configuration.json';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AppSettings {
  public settings!: IAppConfig;
  constructor() {
      this.settings = appSetting as IAppConfig;
  }
}
```

Will probably end up creating both a static Settings and a non-static Settings varialbe on the service class. The non-static one is needed during application start it seems.